# Hangouts chat adapter for botframework is not working

Tags: node.js, botframework, google-hangouts

I am trying to integrate hangouts chat with v4 bot framework

i used this code

```
const adapter = new HangoutsAdapter({
    token: process.env.GOOGLE_TOKEN,
    google_auth_params: {
        credentials: process.env.GOOGLE_CREDS
    }
});

const server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
     adapter.processActivity(req, res, async(context) => {
         await context.sendActivity('I heard a message!');
     });
});
```

but as mentioned in the docs,

https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/tree/main/packages/botbuilder-adapter-hangouts

i coudnt find the token, i can receive the message inside `server.post`, but the code inside `adapter.processActivity` is not working.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can't find the token?

Comment: @ste means, in the doc, it says that, the token is provided in the configuration tab for hangouts chat , but, its no longer there.

Comment: If the location of the token isn't clear or has changed when on the Google Hangouts dev portal, I would recommend reaching out to Google support to get updated information about where to access it. While the Botkit docs should be updated to accurately reflect information, Botkit doesn't control Google resources.